# Streaming from Vimeo using Unity SDK works from editor, but won't load video in a build

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, vimeo

I've downloaded the Unity Vimeo SDK and gotten a video to stream in the editor without a problem. But in a build (I've tried both Android and Windows) the video player screen remains grey and the video never loads. This happens even with the example scenes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback! Are you saving the scene and adding it to build settings before trying to build? would also recommend toggling `Development Build` and `Script Debugging` on so you can [see console errors in Unity during runtime](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/708/how-can-i-see-the-unity-debug-log-output-from-a-running-app-on-the-device)

Comment: The console in the build gives me this error: A script behaviour (probably Vimeo.Player.VimeoPlayer?) has a different serialization layout when loading (Read 23 bytes but expected 6020 bytes). Did you #ifdef UNITY_EDITOR a section of your serialized properties in any of your scripts?

Comment: Never mind! I updated Unity and got the newest version of the SDK and everything works fine now.